# Reproduce figure from paper on Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, transmission, barrier, energy

I want to reproduce Fig. 2 on Matlab from this paper (https://www.docdroid.net/S6RGMXM/yamamoto1990-article-theoreticalstudyofresonanttunn-pdf) for a study:

[image]

It's about the resonant tunneling in double barrier structures, my code so far:

```
clear
clc

m0 = 0.0785*9.10938356*10^(-31);
h_barra = 6.62607004*10^(-34)/(2*pi); % m^2 kg/s
V0 = 0.3228;
Lb = 4e-9;
Lw = 6e-9;
ev = 1.602176634*10^(-19); % 1eV= 1.602176634 10^(-19) J

i = 1;

E_ini = 0;
step = 0.01;
E_end = 0.5;


for E=E_ini:step:E_end

    k = (sqrt(2*m0*E))/(h_barra);
    b = i*((2*m0*(V0-E))^(1/2))/(h_barra);;
    A = V0*sinh(b)*Lb/(2*((E*(V0-E))^(1/2)));
    H = 2*cosh(b)*Lb*cos(k)*Lw-((2*E-V0)/(E*(V0-E))^(1/2))*sinh(b)*Lb*sin(k)*Lw;

    T2 (i) = abs(1/[1+(A^2*H^2)]);

    i = i + 1;

end

E=[E_ini:step:E_end];
plot (E,T2)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

All the equations are taken from page 2, I've check them many times, probe differents forms and no way to reproduce the original graph!!

What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Anyone could guide me a bit? :(